# How to implement a Drawer navigator in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

Hi i 'm new to react native how to implement a drawer navigator in react native. Actually i'm following this doc

**Updated:**

code for home page is as follows

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state= {
            icon: null
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <Container>
          <Header style={{backgroundColor:'pink'}} >
             <Button
             transparent
             onPress= {() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}>
             <Icon
             style= {{color: '#ffffff', fontSize:25, paddingTop:0}}
             name="bars"             
             />
             </Button>
             </Header>
             <Content>
             </Content>
        </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

also

**index.js**

```
import CourseListing from './CourseListing';
import SideBar from './SideBar/SideBar';
import {DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Profile from './Profile';

const MyHome =DrawerNavigator(
{
CourseListing: {screen: CourseListing},
Profile: {screen: Profile},
},
{
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
}
);
```

I'm getting this error 
[image: DrawerNavigation]

Comment: Which library are you using for navigation?

Comment: I'm using `react-navigation`

Comment: use react-native-router-flux library instead of react-navigation. It provide simple documentation to integrate drawer menu and navigation between screens.

Comment: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: It's quite simple. Where are you having a problem?

Comment: Sorry i updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the documentation which is great, I also recommend watching [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQomEMw93W8).

I would suggest creating a file called Router.js. It could look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Screens1 from ... // Import all your screens here
import Screens2 from ...
import Screens3 from ... 

// The DrawerNavigator uses all the screens

export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
   Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
   Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
   Screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
});
```

In your root (usually called App.js) make sure to import MyDrawer:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MyDrawer } from '(correct path here)/Router.js';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return <MyDrawer />;
  }
}
```

Now when the app starts Screen1 will be loaded. Each of the screens has a side menu because of the DrawerNavigator. To open the menu in any screen, use the following method:

```
_openMenu() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much working great..but there is mistake return `MyDrawer` in `App.js` instead of `RootNavigator`.

Comment: Only one screen is showing in side bar `Screen 1`..Why like that?

Comment: I edited my answer. Try deleting the StackNavigator and only use DrawerNavigator like i show in my new answer.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add your own custom component like you already did:   contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />  to DrawerNavigator and it should work as the new menu.

Comment: Okay thank you..how do i style this DrawerNavigator?

Comment: For that you would need to create a custom drawer component and customize it. Like in your example you use contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />, just style it with some touchables, text, backgroundColor and so on.

Comment: No i am just following your answer..so how to make a custom sidebar for this ?

Answer (score 0):

it's so, implement drawer such as `stack-navgation` 
exmaple :

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {signIn,drawer} from 'scene'

const RouteConfigs =  { 
    signIn
}

const DrawerNavigatorConfig = { 
    drawerPosition:'right',
    drawerType:'front',
    hideStatusBar:true,
    contentComponent:drawer
}

export default createDrawerNavigator(RouteConfigs, DrawerNavigatorConfig);
```

the important part is `contentComponent` in `DrawerNavigatorConfig`. it's a view that shows in the drawer when it opens

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import color from '../../../constants/color'
import Attendance from '../../ExtraScreens/Attendance/Attendance'
import KIETDigitalDirectory from '../../ExtraScreens/KIETDigitalDirectory/KIETDigitalDirectory'
import KIETExtensions from '../../ExtraScreens/KIETExtensions/KIETExtensions'
import StudentRedressal from '../../ExtraScreens/StudentRedressal/StudentRedressal'
//
import Ticketing from '../../ExtraScreens/Ticketing/Ticketing'
import TicketingApply from '../../ExtraScreens/Ticketing/TicketingApply'
//
import Grievance from '../../ExtraScreens/EmployeeGrievance/Grievance'
import GrievanceApply from '../../ExtraScreens/EmployeeGrievance/GrievanceApply'
export default class Extra extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
        return (
            <Drawer.Navigator
                drawerType="back"
            // openByDefault
            // overlayColor="transparent"
            >
                <Drawer.Screen name="KIET Extensions" component={KIETExtensions} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Grievance" component={GrievanceStack} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Ticketing" component={TicketingStack} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Student Redressal" component={StudentRedressal} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Attendance" component={Attendance} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="KIET Digital Directory" component={KIETDigitalDirectory} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        )
    }
}

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const GrievanceStack = (props) => (
    <StackNavigator.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Grievance"
        mode="card"
        headerMode="none"enter code here>
        <StackNavigator.Screen name="Grievance" component={Grievance} />
        <StackNavigator.Screen name="Grievance Apply" component={GrievanceApply} />
    </StackNavigator.Navigator>
)
const TicketingStack = (props) => (
    <StackNavigator.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Ticketing"
        mode="card"
        headerMode="none"
    >`enter code here`
        <StackNavigator.Screen name="Ticketing" component={Ticketing} />
        <StackNavigator.Screen name="Ticketing Apply" component={TicketingApply} />
    </StackNavigator.Navigator>
)
```